# transform union query to join query

Tags: sql, join

I have a simple database schema composed of 3 tables

**User**
id
name
matricule

**Document**
id
serial
user_id(owner of document : foreign key to User(id))

**User_Document** (join table)
user_id
document_id

I want all document serial from both user sources : owner of document and join table . The query is filtered by a list of users matricule

I managed to achieve the desired goal with union query :

```
select d.serial from Document d  
INNER JOIN  users u ON u.id = d.user_id 
where u.matricule IN ('1234')
UNION
select d.serial from Document d 
inner join User_Document ud on d.id = ud.document_id 
inner join users u on ud.user_id = u.id 
where u.matricule IN ('1234')
```

How to arrive to the same result with only a join query ? I need as well skip document with no serial ( this case is possible)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT d.serial
FROM Document d 
    LEFT JOIN User_Document ud
        ON d.id = ud.document_id 
    LEFT JOIN users u
        on ud.user_id = u.id 
    LEFT JOIN users u2
        ON d.user_id = u2.id
WHERE d.serial IS NOT NULL
AND 
(
    ISNULL(u.matricule,'') IN ('1234')
    OR ISNULL(u2.matricule,'') IN ('1234')
)
```

Comment: Interesting.  This query can return duplicates, as it is now written, whereas your version doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to remove the `join`s?  Probably the most efficient query would use `exists`:

```
select d.*
from documents d
where d.serial is not null and
      (exists (select 1
               from users u
               where u.id = d.user_id and u.matricule = '1234'
              ) or
       exists (select 1
               from user_document ud join
                    users u
                    on u.id = d.user_id 
               where ud.document_id = d.id and u.matricule = '1234'
              )
      );
```

For this, you would then want indexes on `users(id, matricule)`, `user_documents(document_id, user_id)`, and `documents(serial, user_id, document_id)`.

The use of indexes saves the elimination of duplicates -- which should be a big win for this type of query.

Comment: I don't want remove join but union . You are right , i will need some indexes when the table will grown . Your query works well too . Thank you very much